# The asymptotic distribution of a Pearson Chi-Square test statistic (test for independence)

Tags: chi-squared-test, convergence, contingency-tables

There are many different [Pearson Chi-Square tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence). The test statistics are always a sum of scaled and squared deviations. Some are written as a single sum, and some are written as a double sum (the elements of a double sum are usually displayed in a contingency table).

**I understand the derivation of the null distribution for some tests, but I don't how these proofs also apply to the other tests.** I'm interested in proving the asymptotic distribution for **double** sum test statistic, the test statistic that tests whether two categorical factors are independent. I'm familiar with proofs for the **single** sum case, but I cannot connect the two.

---

My favorite proof is the first one in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.09171.pdf). It goes as follows:

Suppose we have many $k$-dimensional count vectors, and that they each follow a [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) (or Categorical distribution in this case): $\mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{X}_2, \ldots, \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Multinomial}(1,\mathbf{p}).$ The standard central limit theorem gives us
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{\mathbf{X}} - \mathbf{p}) \overset{d}{\to} \text{Normal}(0, \Sigma)
$$
where $n$ is the number of vectors we have and
$$
\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1(1-p_1) & -p_1p_2 & \cdots & -p_1p_k \\
-p_1p_2 & p_2(1-p_2) & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-p_kp_1 & -p_kp_2 & \cdots & p_k(1-p_k)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a (singular/non invertible) covariance matrix. If you remove the last, say, element of $\bar{X}$ (call it $\bar{X}^*$), then you still have
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}^* - \mathbf{p}^*) \overset{d}{\to} \text{Normal}(0, \Sigma^*)
$$
where $\Sigma^*$ is now intvertible and so
$$
n(\bar{X}^* - \mathbf{p}^*)^\intercal (\Sigma^*)^{-1}(\bar{X}^* - \mathbf{p}^*) \overset{d}{\to} \chi^2(\text{rank}(\Sigma^*))
$$
with $\text{rank}(\Sigma^*) = k-1$.

---

As the paper explains in equations (7-9) $n(\bar{X}^* - \mathbf{p}^*)^\intercal (\Sigma^*)^{-1}(\bar{X}^* - \mathbf{p}^*)$ is the same as writing the test statistic in the [more typical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic):
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(O_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}.
$$

Great, so this is fine, but how do we use the above proof to show that [this test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence)
$$
\sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^c \frac{(O_{ij} - E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}}\overset{d}{\to} \chi^2( (r-1)(c-1))
$$
follows a chi-square, too? **How can we string out or vec-out a contingency table in the right way so that it follows a Multinomial and the same proof applies?**

My attempt involves $\text{vec}$-ing out the contingency table, writing that as a multinomial with a probability vector $\mathbf{p} = \text{vec}(\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b}^\intercal)$, but after invoking the central limit theorem and getting a singular normal distribution with covariance $\text{diag}(\mathbf{p}) - \mathbf{p}\mathbf{p}^\intercal$, I'm not sure how to throw out $(r + c - 1)$ elements of the vector to get a nonsingular normal distribution that squares to the test statistic.

Comment: The real difficulty of generalizing the proof of the goodness of fit test (where $p^*$ is non-random) to the independence test does not lie in from 1D to 2D, instead, it is the estimated parameters (that is, in your last expression, $E_{ij}$ is random, as opposed to $np_i$ which is non-random), which determines the degrees of freedom of the limiting distribution and requires new asymptotic tools.  For this reason, the derivation of this very well-known result is rarely detailed in most textbooks.  Luckily, Chapter 17 of *Asymptotic Statistics* by A. W. van der Vaart discussed this in-depth.

Comment: Good reference, yeah 17.3 and 17.4 are what I need